# Ionic 2 is installed, but it's not showing on ionic info

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, npm, ionic2

I installed Ionic 2 and cordova, but it's not showing on ionic info. So I am not able to run my ionic project on my windows system.

This is the output of `ionic info`:

```
E:\Sandbox\ionic\demoApp>ionic info
******************************************************
 Dependency warning - for the CLI to run correctly,
 it is highly recommended to install/upgrade the following:

 Please install your Cordova CLI to version  >=4.2.0 `npm install -g cordova`

******************************************************

Your system information:

Cordova CLI: Not installed
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.1
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.1.0
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Windows 7
Node Version: v6.9.5
Xcode version: Not installed


******************************************************
 Dependency warning - for the CLI to run correctly,
 it is highly recommended to install/upgrade the following:

 Please install your Cordova CLI to version  >=4.2.0 `npm install -g cordova`

******************************************************

E:\Sandbox\ionic\demoApp>cordova -v
4.3.1
```

Comment: What happens after running `npm install -g cordova` ?

Comment: From what I see, Ionic 2 is installed (`Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.1`) but cordova is not

Comment: @Huiting after installed cordova its installed properly and it show the version also....

Comment: No i installed cordova also.....

Comment: @Karthiga try to uninstall everything and install again if you are not able to get the cordova cli verstion then try this command `npm install -g cordova@6.3.0` i sure it will do the trick

Answer (score 0):

you need to check , whether it exists here :

> C:\Users\yourPC\AppData\Roaming\npm

and you also need to set environment variables for the same, make sure your variable name , "Path" have values for npm and JDK both. 
 Your desktop/laptop might need a restart after this process

Comment: yeah I m having ionic in this directory **C:\Users\yourPC\AppData\Roaming\npm** and my path have value **npm**

Comment: does your path value have jdk ?

Comment: you are running an ionic app to make an hybrid application
 Either you have ionic 1 , or ionic 2 !! 
ionic 1 supports (iOS and android )
ionic 2 supports( iOS , android and windows )
 so in both cases we have android. and base of android is java. 
 hence to make any android application work , u need to install JDK.

May i knw which version of ionic are u using 
  by running :-ionic -v on cmd.

Comment: yeah i understood but only for running my application on browser still i need jdk?????so without jdk may i not able to run ionic app on web browser??? my ionic version is  **E:\Sandbox\ionic\demoApp>ionic -v
2.2.1**

Comment: its working fine now after giving this path to environment variable  **C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\bin**

Comment: have fun with ionic 2 !!